# Resize Bootstrap Panel with Tabs on Visible Content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I am implementing something in paper.js where in my application it will be in a bootstrap panel that isn't visible when the page first loads. So far I am not sure how to do it without having it render way off the screen and then translate it into position later. Here is a demo:

http://codepen.io/ajhalls/pen/pRmNVd

Click as many times as you want on the Reload Paper.js tab and it still won't load until it is visible. Any tips?

I am new to canvas and paper.js so I am not sure if it is a canvas issue, or paper.js.

Please ignore this code, it is required to post some code with any links to codepen :)

```
var box = new paper.Shape.Rectangle({
  point: [800, 450],
  size: [100, 100],
  fillColor: "green",
  locked: true
});
```

Comment: So in a way ... you want to hide the parent(the panel) while showing the child within it (the canvas) ??

Comment: I don't want it to be visible, but I want it to not need another action to load after opening the panel. As it is now I have to click to open the panel, then click to load the canvas, when it should only need a single click.

Comment: Ok, so would this work - Try triggering a click `$(".ReloadPaper").trigger('click');` inside say 'Show Panel' function ie. `$("body").on('click', ".ShowAnimationPanel", function(){`-- [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/egaVpE)

Comment: That worked great on codepen, but for some reason it didn't work on my application. I did find a work around by using a timeout: `setTimeout(function() {
RebuildEditor();
}, 300);`

Comment: Hmm .. are there any ajax calls being made in your application which is not available on codepen ? Did you find the solution then ?